# Changing multiple states on button's click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

In my react app i have a list of cars returned from an axios call, each car has an attribute inside it called refundable and it's boolean either true or false, and i have a button and a disabled input, i want when i click on this button if the refundable is true to enable the input and if it's false to hide the input and show a sentence that this car is not refundable, the code i made checks if refundable is true or not and it enables the input, but if it was false it shows the false sentence for all of the cars in the list, here is what I'm doing:

**Initial state:**

```
state={cars: [],isInputDisabled: [], isVisible: true }
```

**Function on button's click:**

```
changeDisableState = (id, i) => {
    const car = this.state.cars.find(x => x.id === id);
    let isInputDisabled = this.state.isInputDisabled;
    isInputDisabled[i] = !isInputDisabled[i];
    if (car.refundable == true) {
      this.setState({ isInputDisabled });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isVisible: false });
    }
  };
```

**Rendering cars:**

```
renderCars() {
  const cars = this.state.cars;
  return cars.map((car, i) => (
   <div key={car.id}>
    <Button onClick={() => this.changeDisableState(car.id, i)}>Check</Button>
   {this.state.isVisible ? 
    <input
    disabled={!this.state.isInputDisabled[i]}/> : <p>Can't be refundable</p>}
   </div> 
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing something in your code:

```
changeDisableState = (id, i) => {
    const car = this.state.cars.find(x => x.id === id);
    let isInputDisabled = this.state.isInputDisabled;
    if (car.refundable == true) {
      this.setState({ isInputDisabled[i] : !isInputDisabled[i] });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isVisible: false });
    }
  };
```

also

this line

```
 disabled={!this.state.isInputDisabled[i]}/>
```

is not clear. It reads as "make my input disabled if my state value for isInputDisable is false" - shouldn't it be inveresed?

Comment: you're right but there is a problem with setting the state in your code, and what about the other part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `isVisible` state for each car object.

```
{car.isVisible ? <input ... /> : <p>Can't be refundable</p>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another state variable for recently clicked `id`. And then only render sentence for active id

```
changeDisableState = (id, i) => {
    const car = this.state.cars.find(x => x.id === id);
    let isInputDisabled = this.state.isInputDisabled;
    isInputDisabled[i] = !isInputDisabled[i];
    if (car.refundable == true) {
      this.setState({ isInputDisabled,activeid:id });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isVisible: false, activeid:id });
    }
  };


renderCars() {
  const cars = this.state.cars;
  return cars.map((car, i) => (
   <div key={car.id}>
    <Button onClick={() => this.changeDisableState(car.id, i)}>Check</Button>
   {this.state.isVisible ? 
    <input
    disabled={!this.state.isInputDisabled[i]}/> : this.state.activeid === car.id && <p>Can't be refundable</p>}
   </div> 
  ));
}
```

Comment: your code hides all of the input fields if one of them is false

Comment: @Monica Jennings Can you please give working code so i can test